# Ordenar campo Varchar levando em conta grupos e subgrupos

Tags: mysql, sql

Ppreciso ordenar os valores abaixo em ordem crescente. São do tipo Varchar e as soluções que encontrei até agora para MySQL não funcionaram.

Um exemplo do tipo de dado seria `1.12.02`, pois estes valores servem como código específico para uma tabela de plano de contas. O problema é que valores como `1.2` estão vindo após `1.15` e assim por diante.

Os números possuem até 3 subníveis depois do primeiro ponto, e cada subnível pode ter até 3 caracteres.

Por exemplo, aós invés de:

```
1.1   
1.1.01   
1.10   
1.11   
1.12   
1.12.01   
1.15.1   
1.2
```

Deveria ser:

```
1.1    
1.1.01   
1.2   
1.10   
1.11    
1.12   
1.12.01   
1.15.1
```

Comment: Para falar a verdade, o maior problema é armazenar errado os valores. Se eles tem esse sentido numérico pretendido, deveria armazenar como `10502001` em vez de `1.5.2.01`, e formatar na tela, lembrando sempre de deixar o número de dígitos por unidade reservado de maneira razoável. Isso é muito comum em sistemas com plano de contas, árvores de documentação, sistemas de versionamento etc.

Comment: Olá ! Exatamente, minha necessidade é que seja feita ordenação numérica, porém acabei n postando toda listagem pois é muito grande, os maiores valores tem até 3 subníveis após o primeiro ponto, podendo ter até 3 caracteres cada nível.

Comment: O ponto deve ser usado somente na tela, e não no DB. Normalmente não se guarda formatação na base de dados. Se precisar formatar, faça na linguagem cliente do sistema (imagino que você esteja usando alguma). Por exemplo, um CNPJ normalmente é apenas um campo com digitos, sem pontos e traços. Um plano de contas apenas uma string de números prefixados por zero (normalmente 2 casas no nivel 2 e 3 casas ou mais em diante). Inclusive, isto evita que por engano haja 1.02 e 1.2 na base, que daria uma confusão danada. Um formato ABBCCCDDDEEE geralmente resolve.

Comment: Editei e pus um exemplo, favor confirmar se está de acordo com o desejado. Obrigado !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O maior problema foi na decisão de modelagem, que priorizou a armazenagem do valor formatado, e não o valor semântico.

### Solução preferida: remodelar

A solução ideal seria converter a coluna para algum formato que tivesse o *padding* das casas preservado, seja string ou preferencialmente numérico caso o valor máximo com padding "caiba" nos dígitos do tipo escolhido.

Em vez de

```
1.15
1.2.17.01
```

se armazenaria, por exemplo:

```
01015000000
01002017001
```

Usei o formato AABBBCCCDDD (duas casas no primeiro nível, e 3 nos seguintes), mas isto deve ser ajustado conforme sua aplicação.

Os pontos seriam colocados somente na exibição em tela, e retirados no *input*, com a respectiva validação e formatação.

### Solução intermediária

Uma possível solução é a criação de uma Function no MySQL que desmembre a *string* em grupos, multiplicando seus fatores por uma constante correspondente aos possíveis níveis, ordenando efetivamente.

Outra delas é usar substrings, mas isso envolve extrair cada grupo, acrescentar zeros antes e cortar numa medida fixa:

```
SELECT
  conta
FROM
  planodecontas
ORDER BY
  0 + SUBSTRING_INDEX( CONCAT( conta, '.0.0.0' ), '.', 1 ),
  0 + SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( CONCAT( conta, '.0.0.0' ), '.', 2 ), '.', -1),
  0 + SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( CONCAT( conta, '.0.0.0' ), '.', 3 ), '.', -1),
  0 + SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( CONCAT( conta, '.0.0.0' ), '.', 4 ), '.', -1)
```

O problema nos dois casos é que ficam funções "feias e caras" para uso na ordenação. Fazer na aplicação-cliente (ordenar depois de recuperar, com a linguagem principal do código), pode acabar sendo melhor.

### Solução "orientada a gambiarra":

Por acaso, tem uma função que é feita para interpretar números IPV4, que são strings com formato `AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD`, que é a `INET_ATON`

```
SELECT
   conta
FROM
   planodecontas
ORDER BY
   INET_ATON( SUBSTRING_INDEX( CONCAT( conta, '.0.0.0' ), '.', 4 ) );
```

A limitação é que a `INET_ATON` precisa de quantidade fixa de grupos para uma comparação equilibrada, e somente **funciona com valores de 0 a 255 por grupo**.

Para alinhar os grupos, usamos

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX( CONCAT( conta, '.0.0.0' ), '.', 4 )
```

Que pega 4 grupos separados com `.` da *string* concatenada.

Não recomendo, mas é bom você saber que existe.

Comment: Ótimo @Bacco o inet_aton() ira ajudar por hora, a longo prazo irei usar a sua sugestão de remodelagem da estrutura.

Obrigado !

Comment: Agora entendi o propósito @Bacco, vou optar pela remodelagem. De qualquer forma obrigado pela ajuda !

Comment: @FelipeDM adicionei dois exemplos testados que resolvem, espero que satisfaçam no sentido de fechar a questão. Se tiver dúvidas avise. O 1º exemplo pode ser facilmente convertido para você gerar uma coluna remodelada, caso os dados já estejam inseridos na base. Só de curiosidade, meu primeiro sistema de plano de contas usava campos binários, de 1 byte no primeiro grupo, e 2 nos seguintes. Naquela época se economizava espaço no DB :)

Comment: a solução intermediaria funcionou exatamente como eu necessitava, muito obrigado pelo tempo disposto !!!

Comment: Uma solução simples pode ser trabalhar com as mascara do tipo 1.01   
1.01.01   
1.10   
1.11   
1.12   
1.12.01   
1.15.1   
1.02   ou seja com as colunas com números de decimais "fixos" , mantem a modelagem (ruim) mas não requer maiores mudanças no escopo da coisa ,

Comment: @Motta até resolve, mas se é pra fazer isso acho que compensa fazer o "serviço completo", e garantir a unicidade da informação com um formato sem ambiguidade. Imagino que o trabalho que dá pra garantir esse formato constante seja o mesmo de fazer como eu mencionei. Mas realmente, ter o padding constante já é alguma coisa. Resolve o problema da ordenação.

Comment: @Bacco , já passei por um problema a ANS  (Agência Nacional de Saúde) definiu itens assim e era um problema ordenar pois caia sempre na questão do ordenamento de "alfa" , como era um padrão externo e obrigatório pelas Operadoras (trabalho em uma) a solução foi criar uma coluna só para ordenar , pelas formas normais daria até cadeia...

Comment: @Motta Eu tenho nojo do TI da coisa pública, é um festival de horrores. Eu teria uma lista imensa de decisões absurdas com as quais fui (e ainda sou obrigado a conviver) se fosse parar pra contar.