# Ordenar classificação de acordo com a base de dados | PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho 3 tipos de classificação, seguindo a coerência: `1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2` - Tenho que exibir na frente dos títulos, cada conteúdo que pertence a sua classificação, ficando da seguinte maneira na hora de exibir na tela:

```
> 1. Meu conteudo Administrativo
> 1.1 Novo Conteudo
> 1.1.1 André Ribeiro
> 1.1.2 Teste de Gestão de Pessoas
```

Precisa seguir de cada campo.

Estou usando o codeigniter, mas pode ser feito em PHP básico de SQL mesmo, e eu ajusto no codeigniter.

Eu tentei fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
$this->db->select("coe_classificacao");
$this->db->where("set_base != ", 12); // conteudo sobre
$this->db->order_by("coe_classificacao", "ASC");
$this->db->group_by("coe_classificacao");
$consulta = $this->db->get('conteudos')->result();

foreach($consulta as &$valor){
    $this->db->select("coe_titulo, coe_classificacao, coe_classificacao_1, coe_classificacao_2");
    $this->db->where("set_base != ", 12); // conteudo sobre
    $this->db->where("coe_classificacao", $valor->coe_classificacao);
    $this->db->order_by("coe_classificacao_1", "ASC");
    $retorno = $this->db->get('conteudos')->result();

        foreach($retorno as &$valor_retorno){
            $this->db->select("coe_titulo, coe_classificacao_1, coe_classificacao_2");
            $this->db->where("set_base != ", 12); // conteudo sobre
            $this->db->where("coe_classificacao_1", $valor_retorno->coe_classificacao_1);
            $this->db->order_by("coe_classificacao_2", "ASC");
            $valor_retorno->sub = $this->db->get('conteudos')->result();                    
        }
}
```

Mas de igual forma, não me traz o resultado esperado, acredito que podem desconsiderar o que eu fiz.

**A questão é: Como eu faço para transformar tudo em isso em array, para que eu consiga exibir da forma que eu transcrevi?**

Comment: o método `result()` retorna o resultado em formato de `objetos` ou `arrays`? Desculpe, codeigniter não é minha praia...

Comment: result é array(), ai por isso dou um foreach() se eu retornar row() ele vem como obj

Comment: Talvez ajude: [Ordenar campo Varchar levando em conta grupos e subgrupos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/155037/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua lógica está correta aparentemente, me parece faltar apenas "salvar" os dados referêntes a cada item:

```
$this->db->select("coe_classificacao");
$this->db->where("set_base != ", 12); // conteudo sobre
$this->db->order_by("coe_classificacao", "ASC");
$this->db->group_by("coe_classificacao");
$consulta =  json_decode(json_encode($this->db->get('conteudos')->result_array()), True);

foreach($consulta as $key => $valor){
    $this->db->select("coe_titulo, coe_classificacao, coe_classificacao_1, coe_classificacao_2");
    $this->db->where("set_base != ", 12); // conteudo sobre
    $this->db->where("coe_classificacao", $valor->coe_classificacao);
    $this->db->order_by("coe_classificacao_1", "ASC");
    $retorno = $this->db->get('conteudos')->result_array();
    $consulta[$key][] =  json_decode(json_encode($retorno), True);

        foreach($consulta[$key] as $key_neto => $valor_retorno){
            $this->db->select("coe_titulo, coe_classificacao_1, coe_classificacao_2");
            $this->db->where("set_base != ", 12); // conteudo sobre
            $this->db->where("coe_classificacao_1", $valor_retorno->coe_classificacao_1);
            $this->db->order_by("coe_classificacao_2", "ASC");
            $consulta[$key][$key_neto][] = 
    $consulta[$key][] =  json_decode(json_encode($this->db->get('conteudos')->result_array()), True);                    
        }
}
```

Creio que isso resolva!

Comment: Até ai, ok, isto é simples. Porém, no PHP puro, como eu faço para transformar tudo em isso em array, para que eu consiga exibir da forma que eu transcrevi?

Comment: desculpe, agora entendi realmente a pergunta...

Comment: Então, veio este erro: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in, e a linha é esta:  $consulta[$key][] = $retorno;

Comment: Isso quer dizer que os objetos retornados estão em um `array`, porém são `objetos` de fato, vou pesquisar como converter e atualizo a resposta...

Comment: Substitui `result()` por `result_array()`

Comment: Da erro igual, mas estou tentando aqui

Comment: realmente não deu certo rsrsrs

Comment: Cara, como não conheço o framework, resolvi de outra maneir...teoricamente...rsrs tenta isso ai!

Answer (score 1):

Código PHP, não entendi o que quer dizer com `PHP` puro, uso o `mysqli`:

```
$sql = "SELECT coe_class, coe_class1, coe_class2, coe_titulo FROM TESTE ORDER BY coe_class,coe_class1,coe_class2;"
  or die("Erro na consulta: " . mysqli_error($sql));

$query = $conn->query($sql);

if ( $query->num_rows > 0 ){
  while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()){
      $out = '';
      $out = ($dados['coe_class']  > 0 ? $dados['coe_class']  .'.' : '') .
             ($dados['coe_class1'] > 0 ? $dados['coe_class1'] .'.' : '') .
             ($dados['coe_class2'] > 0 ? $dados['coe_class2'] .'.' : '');

      echo rtrim(trim($out), '.') . ' - ' . $dados['coe_titulo'];
      echo '<br>';
  }
} else {
    echo 'Nenhuma linha retornada.';
}
```

Exemplo de saida:

> 1 - Administrativo
>   1.1 - Novo Conteudo
>   1.1.1 - Andre
>   1.1.2 - Teste de Gestão

Comment: Eu uso o codeigniter, mas dessa forma, não vou conseguir usar...

Comment: `php` puro é justamente isso, quando utilizamos um `framework` de desenvolvimento, não é necessário montar a consulta na "unha", ou mesmo criar `classes` de conexão, o framework já provê tudo isso e normalmente, como no caso deste usuário, fornece um `ORM` para manipulação de dados.

Comment: Sim, acredito que daria certo, estou verificando